# problem in react native chat app algorithm

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, chat, react-native-gifted-chat

I am building an app contains chat but i couldn't figure out somethings.

1. Notifications: I can send notifications to devices but they appear everytime (app in on screen or not) but i want to send "chat" notification only the chat page not open. I think i need to send data notifications instead of normal notifications.
2. Storing chats: I can't pull all the chats eveytime user wants to see messages. I need to store them and show only the new messages. How can i seperate them? Device has to say i have messages until this timestamp give me newer ones.

I am using firebase and gifted chat. I can give you any version codes if you want.

Comment: give us some more details

Comment: 1. User should get notifcation when there is a new message but only in another screen or app not active.

2. User should get only new messages. because everytime user enter i can't send him all the messages.

The sending, receiving and store them on firebase is done but needs fine tuning about above ones.